# Graph clustering algorithm for two clusters of same size

Tags: clustering, graph-theory

I have a graph of 100 nodes. I know that there are 2 clusters of nodes of equal size 50. I created (kind of like a training set) the following instance of the problem (see below, I have some values to compare nodes interactions). I could create more matrix like that and learn on them if needed but I'm not sure it's the best way to solve the problem.
Anyway, I'm looking for a graph clustering algorithm well suited for my problem (2 clusters of equal size).

In the following visualization, the rows have been sorted so that the two clusters are well separated.

[image: affinity matrix]

Comment: When the sizes of the clusters are known in advance the problem is classically described as 'Graph partitioning'.  I have worked only in graph clustering, so unfortunately I cannot recommend particular methods, but it is probably worthwhile seeking out methods from this field (graph partitioning).